# How to put a wallet credential to composer-wallet-inmemory?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

How to put a wallet credential to `composer-wallet-inmemory` v.0.19.5?

This is the method:

```
/**
     * Add a new credential to the wallet.
     *
     * @param {string} name The name of the credentials.
     * @param {string} value The credentials.
     * @return {Promise} A promise that is resolved when
     * complete, or rejected with an error.
     */
    put(name, value) {

        if (!name) {
            return Promise.reject(new Error('Name must be specified'));
        }

        if (value instanceof IdCard || value instanceof Buffer || value instanceof String  || typeof value === 'string'){
            this.store.set( this._path(name),value);
            return Promise.resolve();
        }else {
            return Promise.reject(new Error('Unkown type being stored'));
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be trying to interact directly with the composer-wallet implementations. You should use an instance of AdminConnection to manage cards in the card store

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/api/admin-adminconnection

and configure your environment to use the inmemory wallet as described here

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/business-network/cloud-wallets

Comment: I dont want to use `composer-admin`, its possible to import card with `composer-client`? I know that client dont have this method nowadays, but it is possible?

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't want to use composer-admin npm module. This capability won't be copied into composer-client. Card management is an operational capability.

Comment: I am building a serverless library, and dont need to use most of the composer-admin functions and also dont have enough memory to add it all. So I just need to handle the import card function inside composer-client

Comment: You would need to replicate the logic performed in composer-admin yourself to import a card correctly but that means using internal apis which could change. There aren't any plans at the moment to merge apis in admin into client, but that could change in the future. Does including admin add much overhead ? npm should ensure common modules are not replicated, so even if not at first you could try running npm dedupe on your application.